# Textfield displaying error message even after the values are inserted

Tags: firebase, validation, flutter, dart

i have used 3 textfields in the code below, i have validated each message and it displays the error message when i click on the raised button but after that when i enter the values it will be still displaying the same error message on the screen can someone please help me.

Here's my code:

```
   import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:toast/toast.dart';

class AddPromo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddPromoState createState() => _AddPromoState();
}

class _AddPromoState extends State<AddPromo> {
  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;

  var priceReductionController = TextEditingController();
  var perReductionController = TextEditingController();
  var promocodeController = TextEditingController();

  bool _validate = false;
  bool _validatePrice = false;
  bool _validatePerReduction = false;
  bool _validatePromoCode = false;


  @override
  void dispose() {
    priceReductionController.dispose();
    perReductionController.dispose();
    promocodeController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Add promo"),backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,),
      body: Column(
        children : <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            controller: priceReductionController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Price Reduction",
                  errorText: _validatePrice ? 'value cant be empty' : null,
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  const Radius.circular(0.0),
                ),
                borderSide: new BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.indigo,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: TextField(
             keyboardType: TextInputType.number,


             controller: perReductionController,
             decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Percentage Reduction",
                 errorText: _validatePerReduction ? 'value cant be empty' : null,
                 border: new  OutlineInputBorder(
               borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.indigo)

             )),


            ),
         ),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: TextField(

             controller: promocodeController,
             decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Promo code",
                 errorText: _validatePromoCode ? 'value cant be empty' : null,
                 border: OutlineInputBorder(

             )),

            ),
         ),
          Spacer(flex:2),
        Container(
          width: 350,

          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.indigo,
            onPressed: () async {

              //perform the validation first
              setState(() {
                priceReductionController.text.isEmpty
                    ? _validatePrice = true
                    : _validatePrice = false;
                perReductionController.text.isEmpty
                    ? _validatePerReduction = true
                    : _validatePerReduction = false;
                promocodeController.text.isEmpty
                    ? _validatePromoCode = true
                    : _validatePromoCode = false;
              });

              //verify that all are fine
              if (_validatePrice || _validatePromoCode || _validatePerReduction) {
                return;
              }

              //store the values into the database
              DocumentReference ref = await databaseReference.collection("promo_codes")
                  .add({
                'percentage_reduction': perReductionController.text,
                'price_reduction': priceReductionController.text,
                'promo_code': promocodeController.text,
              });

              Scaffold.of(context)
                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Promo saved.")))
                  .closed
                  .then((reason) {
                // snackbar is now closed
              });
```

[image: this is how my code looks like when i click on the button without any fields entered and later i filled it with thesevalues]
                  //print(ref.documentID);
                },

[image: the data is getting stored in the database but still the error message is not disapppearing from the scrren]

```
I/OpenGLRenderer( 6519): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer( 6519): Swap behavior 2
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6519): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6519): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6519): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6519): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6519): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/BiChannelGoogleApi( 6519): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@172de21
W/DynamiteModule( 6519): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth( 6519): [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth( 6519): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
D/FirebaseAuth( 6519): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 7pkcfF4j1yVLCnMUn9BE0uvjL2s1 ).
I/flutter ( 6519): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)
W/DynamiteModule( 6519): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6519): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6519): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/dminbookingpag( 6519): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/chatty  ( 6519): uid=10296(m20zero.adminbookingpage) AsyncTask #2 identical 1 line
I/dminbookingpag( 6519): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto( 6519): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
W/dminbookingpag( 6519): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
W/dminbookingpag( 6519): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (light greylist, reflection)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 6519): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/ProviderInstaller( 6519): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/dminbookingpag( 6519): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (light greylist, reflection)
W/dminbookingpag( 6519): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, linking)
W/dminbookingpag( 6519): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, linking)
W/dminbookingpag( 6519): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (light greylist, JNI)
W/dminbookingpag( 6519): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/dminbookingpag( 6519): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (light greylist, linking)
W/dminbookingpag( 6519): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (light greylist, linking)
I/flutter ( 6519): 21
I/flutter ( 6519): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.done, 21, null)
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6519): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6519): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6519): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6519): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
E/flutter ( 6519): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.
E/flutter ( 6519): No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to Scaffold.of(). This usually happens when the context provided is from the same StatefulWidget as that whose build function actually creates the Scaffold widget being sought.
E/flutter ( 6519): There are several ways to avoid this problem. The simplest is to use a Builder to get a context that is "under" the Scaffold. For an example of this, please see the documentation for Scaffold.of():
E/flutter ( 6519):   https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html
E/flutter ( 6519): A more efficient solution is to split your build function into several widgets. This introduces a new context from which you can obtain the Scaffold. In this solution, you would have an outer widget that creates the Scaffold populated by instances of your new inner widgets, and then in these inner widgets you would use Scaffold.of().
E/flutter ( 6519): A less elegant but more expedient solution is assign a GlobalKey to the Scaffold, then use the key.currentState property to obtain the ScaffoldState rather than using the Scaffold.of() function.
E/flutter ( 6519): The context used was:
E/flutter ( 6519):   AddPromo
E/flutter ( 6519): #0      Scaffold.of (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1316:5)
E/flutter ( 6519): #1      _AddPromoState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:adminbookingpage/screens/addPromo.dart:119:24)
E/flutter ( 6519): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6519): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter ( 6519): #3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter ( 6519): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 6519): #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter ( 6519): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter ( 6519): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:199:7)
E/flutter ( 6519): #8      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:467:9)
E/flutter ( 6519): #9      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter ( 6519): #10     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:117:9)
E/flutter ( 6519): #11     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter ( 6519): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:115:18)
E/flutter ( 6519): #13     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:7)
E/flutter ( 6519): #14     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter ( 6519): #15     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter ( 6519): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 6519): #17     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter ( 6519): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter ( 6519): #19     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter ( 6519): #20     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter ( 6519): #21     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter ( 6519): #22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter ( 6519): #23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
```

Comment: are you saying that the toast messge does not dismiss itself event after the given time out?

Comment: i have updated my post and clearly explained what is problem kindly check

Answer (score 2):

> Blockquote
> Form(key: _formKey,autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction)

You should add `Autovalidate Mode.onUserInteraction` property into form widget, that allows you to validate the form every time the user changes some values.

Comment: This is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Three mistakes are there in the code.

> 1. You cleared the controller object on button click

Don't clear the controller object. We need to keep the controller object value to maintain the text field state on widget rebuild. 
So, to resolve this, remove the following code snippet from your code

```
        perReductionController.clear();
        priceReductionController.clear();
        promocodeController.clear();
```

> 2. You are keeping only one boolean variable to store validated state of all text fields

That means, even after you fill up the first text field, on button click, the first text field will continue showing the error message just because your second text field is still empty. To solve this, you must keep a boolean variable dedicated to each text field.

The steps are explained below,

**Add three variables**

```
   bool _validatePrice = false;
   bool _validatePerReduction = false;
   bool _validatePromoCode = false;
```

**replace the validations in each text field with appropriate boolean checks.**

For example, for percentage reduction text field, use the following,

```
  errorText: _validatePerReduction ? 'value cant be empty' : null,
```

**replace the following snippet in the button click event function**

```
 priceReductionController.text.isEmpty ? _validate = true :_validate = false;
          perReductionController.text.isEmpty ? _validate = true :_validate = false;
          promocodeController.text.isEmpty ? _validate = true :_validate = false;
```

with

```
  priceReductionController.text.isEmpty
              ? _validatePrice = true
              : _validatePrice = false;
          perReductionController.text.isEmpty
              ? _validatePerReduction = true
              : _validatePerReduction = false;
          promocodeController.text.isEmpty
              ? _validatePromoCode = true
              : _validatePromoCode = false;
```

> 3. You are storing the values into firestore before validating the form.

You should validate the form first and must ensure that everything is fine, then only you may continue to the next step, that is storing it into the database.

So your onPressed function should look like

```
 onPressed: () async {

        //perform the validation first
        setState(() {
          priceReductionController.text.isEmpty
              ? _validatePrice = true
              : _validatePrice = false;
          perReductionController.text.isEmpty
              ? _validatePerReduction = true
              : _validatePerReduction = false;
          promocodeController.text.isEmpty
              ? _validatePromoCode = true
              : _validatePromoCode = false;
        });

        //verify that all are fine
        if (_validatePrice || _validatePromoCode || _validatePerReduction) {
          return;
        }

        //store the values into the database
         DocumentReference ref = await databaseReference.collection("promo_codes")
                  .add({
                'percentage_reduction': perReductionController.text,
                'price_reduction': priceReductionController.text,
                'promo_code': promocodeController.text,
              });

        Scaffold.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Promo saved.")))
            .closed
            .then((reason) {
          // snackbar is now closed
        });

        //print(ref.documentID);
      },
```

### To solve your Toast problem, I suggest you to use the snackbar which is part of the material design.

So, in order to use the snackbar, you must move your scaffold widget into a parent widget as shown below.

```
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Add promo"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
  ),
  body: AddPromo(),
);
```

Then to show the snack bar, replace your Toast snippet with the following

```
 Scaffold.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Promo saved.")))
            .closed
            .then((reason) {
          // snackbar is now closed
        });
```

Comment: i cleared those 3 lines from my code and ran the application but still im facing the same problem

Comment: did you add three boolean fields dedicated to store validated state of each text field? then it must work

Comment: no sir can you please help me how to add those values and where

Comment: thank you sir,i have updated above what i have done recently kindly check

Comment: not working when i click on the button first its displaying error messages after entering the values again the error messages stay on the scrren even after the values are submitted to the database

Comment: no way, kindly check my updated answer and carefully place those snippets.

Comment: And there is one more problem that when i enter two values and click on the button all the fields are showing error messages and oly two fields data is getting stored in the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204170/discussion-between-rohit-and-darish).

Comment: @Rohit that is because you are storing the values before performing the validations,  well that is another mistake, i will update my answer to cover that point too.

Comment: ok sir and can you also please check that toast message of add promocode that is displaying even when the fields are empty

Comment: sir this worked but the values are not getting stored in the database and im getting errors in the console

Comment: @Rohit that must be a different problem. Post it as a separate question and put the complete it is not related to the problem you were talking about initially. I hope all those three issues that you posted initially got solved. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `onFieldSubmitted` of TextFormField

```
 onFieldSubmitted: (value){
                          _setState(() {
                         _validate =  !priceReductionController.text.isEmpty &&
 !perReductionController.text.isEmpty  &&
 !promocodeController.text.isEmpty;
                          });
                        },
```

But instead of using a single _validate it might be good to use three different boolean states or altogether use `Form` https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation widget and use its validate method. instead of handling by yourself

also dont clear controller

```
perReductionController.clear();
priceReductionController.clear();
promocodeController.clear();
```

Comment: sir can you help me out how to do it my code please

Comment: check https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation for example better use Form in such cases

Answer (score 0):

your _validate is always false. kindly check set state method and printing the _validate.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
// Replace TextField() -> TextFormField()
// autovalidate: true;
// validate : (String value) { 
//     // validation rules
// }

Updated code: 

class AddPromo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddPromoState createState() => _AddPromoState();
}

class _AddPromoState extends State<AddPromo> {

  var priceReductionController = TextEditingController();
  var perReductionController = TextEditingController();
  var promocodeController = TextEditingController();
  bool _validate = false;
  bool priceReductionControllerSubmited = false;
  bool perReductionControllerSubmited = false;
  bool promocodeControllerSubmired = false;


  @override
  void dispose() {
    priceReductionController.dispose();
    perReductionController.dispose();
    promocodeController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Add promo"),backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,),
      body: Column(
        children : <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
             controller: priceReductionController,
             autovalidate: true,
             validator: (String value) {
               if(value.isEmpty && !priceReductionControllerSubmited) {
                  return 'value can\'t be empty';
               }
               else {
                 return null;
               }
             },
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Price Reduction",
                errorText: _validate ? 'value cant be empty' : null,
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  const Radius.circular(0.0),
                ),
                borderSide: new BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.indigo,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: TextFormField(
             keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            autovalidate: true,
             validator: (String value) {
               if(value.isEmpty && !perReductionControllerSubmited) {
                  return 'value can\'t be empty';
               }
               else {
                 return null;
               }
             },

             controller: perReductionController,
             decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Percentage Reduction",

                 border: new  OutlineInputBorder(
               borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.indigo)

             )),


            ),
         ),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: TextFormField(
              controller: promocodeController,
             autovalidate: true,
             validator: (String value) {
               if(value.isEmpty && !promocodeControllerSubmired) {
                  return 'value can\'t be empty';
               }
               else {
                 return null;
               }
             },
             decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Promo code",
                 errorText: _validate ? 'value cant be empty' : null,
                 border: OutlineInputBorder(

             )),

            ),
         ),
          Spacer(flex:2),
        Container(
          width: 350,

          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.indigo,

            onPressed: () async {

               DocumentReference ref = await databaseReference.collection("promo_codes").add({
              'percentage_reduction': perReductionController.text,
              'price_reduction': priceReductionController.text,
              'promo_code': promocodeController.text,
                });

           // Toast.show("Promo saved", context);
            print(ref.documentID);


              promocodeController.clear();
              perReductionController.clear();
              priceReductionController.clear();
              setState(() {
                priceReductionControllerSubmited = true;
                promocodeControllerSubmired =true;
                perReductionControllerSubmited =true;
              });

          }, child: Text("Add Promo", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),),),
        )
          ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no sir its only working fine for checking if the fields are empty, the error messages after the values are submitted is not going

Comment: there is some problem with database reference